# How can I paint an image from BufferStrategy to Png file?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, png, bufferstrategy

I've created a Java program that generates snowflakes and I'd like to save the image created as a .png file once the program finishes drawing.

I've searched on Internet, but I've found only programs using BufferedImage, while I use a BufferStrategy, so I don't know exactly where to start.

The draw method in my program uses a BufferStrategy to create the Graphics component.
For example, to draw a simple line the method is:

```
bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
if (bs == null) {
    display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
    return;
}

g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

What I would like is to get an exact copy of what has been drawn on the screen by the program to be saved as a .png image.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: All you need to do is pass the Graphics object (g) that you created into paint/paintComponent/paintAll from the top level down

Comment: If you look here at how I did this back in the day, all you need to do is send your Graphics object to paint: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/print/StandardPrint.java

Comment: Instead of painting to the Graphics context of the BufferedStrategy, paint to Graphics context of the image

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a screenshot and then past it onto MS paint or some other(and better) image editing software like Photoshop or fire alpaca? That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The common denominator between `BufferedStrategy` and `BufferedImage` is `Graphics`, so you want to write a paint routine so that you can simply pass a reference of `Graphics` to it

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50);
}
```

Then you can pass what ever context you want.

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
render(g2d);
g2d.dispose();
```

Then you can use `ImageIO.write` to write the image to disk.  See [Writing/Saving an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) for more details